# Triggering 'connection reset by peer'

Tags: testing, ftp, tcp

I would like to test the logging that happens in our app (an embedded ftp server) when a 'connection reset by peer' error occurs. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/connection-reset-by-peer) explains the source of the error pretty well, but doesn't really explain how to cause one. Does anybody know a way to trigger this error for a TCP connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tcpkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill) seems to do the job well.