# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, httpconnection

I have an HTTP server in Android. I create a new thread for each of the HTTP requests as in the link mentioned:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java.

When I issue multiple GET requests, sometimes I am getting an exception like the following:

```
01-22 10:28:22.779: W/System.err(2019): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)  
01-22 10:28:22.779: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)  
01-22 10:28:22.779: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
01-22 10:28:22.779: W/System.err(2019):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)  
01-22 10:28:22.779: W/System.err(2019):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)     
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)   
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)  
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)  
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.HttpRequestParser.parseHead(HttpRequestParser.java:71)  
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)  
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(AbstractHttpServerConnection.java:141)   
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:135)    
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at com.example.devicecommunication.ConnectService$WorkerThread.run(ConnectService.java:744)    
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)   
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)   
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)   
01-22 10:28:22.784: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)   
01-22 10:28:22.789: W/System.err(2019):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)   
01-22 10:28:22.789: W/System.err(2019):     ... 10 more
```

I am not sure why this occurs. Below is the code used and this exception occurs at `handleRequest()` method or in `conn.close()`.

```
  class WorkerThread extends Thread{
    HttpService httpService;
    HttpServerConnection conn;
    public WorkerThread(HttpService httpService, HttpServerConnection conn){
        super();
        this.httpService = httpService;
        this.conn = conn;
    }       
    public void run(){
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
        
        try {
          Log.d(TAG,"Going to call Handle request here");
                this.httpService.handleRequest(this.conn, context);         
             } catch (ConnectionClosedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG,"Client closed connection exception");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG,"I/O exceptionnnnn " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (HttpException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Unrecoverable HTTP protocol violation: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
           Log.d(TAG,"Inside Finally Block");
          try {              
            this.conn.close(); 
            Log.d(TAG,"Connection closed successfully");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
          }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this occurs or how can it be resolved?

Comment: According to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/android-getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer, it is said to set the keepAlive to false. I tried System.setProperty("http.KeepAlive","false"); and still the issue persists.

Comment: That’s not how you do that. It isn’t a system property, it’s an HTTP header: `connection: close`.

Comment: Are you using a new connection per thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I passed the DefaultHttpServerConnection attribute to the handle() method using the following code snippet, I did not get this exception:

In the WorkerThread class, pass the DefaultHttpServerConnection connection object using the following code:

```
HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
context.setAttribute("XXX",this.conn);
```

In the handle() method, get the connection object using,

```
(DefaultHttpServerConnection)context.getAttribute("XXX");
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: what does this do? It is not possible to observe anything that supposedly solves the problem.