# Get a huge chunk of data from a server to an android app

Tags: android, json, http, servlets, connection

I'm trying to get a large **Json** String from a **server** to an **android** application.

I tried many ways but as soon as the data gets too large I start facing a lot of problems.

Now I managed to get data and I get a problem when I'm trying to get the **String** from the **HttpEntity**. But after approximately 30 seconds of waiting I get the warning below. And my data is lost.

```
02-25 10:51:08.261: W/System.err(13528): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-25 10:51:08.281: W/System.err(13528):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:390)
02-25 10:51:08.286: W/System.err(13528):    at com.mss.annborgadmin.utils.NetworkConnectionHandler.convertStreamToFile(NetworkConnectionHandler.java:55)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at com.mss.annborgadmin.tasks.HistoryTask.doInBackground(HistoryTask.java:120)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at com.mss.annborgadmin.tasks.HistoryTask.doInBackground(HistoryTask.java:1)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-25 10:51:08.291: W/System.err(13528):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-25 10:51:08.296: W/System.err(13528):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-25 10:51:08.296: W/System.err(13528):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-25 10:51:08.296: W/System.err(13528): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-25 10:51:08.301: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-25 10:51:08.301: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:140)
02-25 10:51:08.301: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-25 10:51:08.306: W/System.err(13528):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
02-25 10:51:08.306: W/System.err(13528):    ... 19 more
```

Here's the function I'm using to get the data from the input stream.

```
public static String convertStreamToFile(InputStream is, Context context) 
    {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try 
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                is.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String result = sb.toString();

        File historyFile = FileHandler.openFile(context, "temp.txt");
        FileHandler.writeData(result, historyFile);


        return "done";
    }
```

The warning is about a connection error, but When I call this function, I already got the response's content using:

```
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
Log.d("DEBUG", "CONTENT TO IS");
```

Any idea what causes this? And is there a better way to get a huge Json String from a server to an android phone and parse it?

---

I fixed the issue now thanks to [Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844392/piyush-gupta)'s [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android).

instead of using:

```
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();               
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
result = NetworkConnectionHandler.convertStreamToFile(is, context);
```

I now use:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
result = NetworkConnectionHandler.convertStreamToFile(in, context);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454694/java-net-socketexception-recvfrom-failed-econnreset-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: Thank you I used an **HttpURLConnection** with a **BufferedInputStream** as suggested in the link and now the connection doesn't close and I manage to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's the server's fault - it had to close the connection after each request . it might be that android keeps a pool of connections and use the old one.