# Java Connect Exception: Failed to Connect to local, port 80

Tags: android, mysql, apache, port80

I am building a chat application in Android with backend MySQL, PHP and running on local network with Apache. However, as a user attempts to sign up, the LogCat displays an error as "Java.net.ConnectionException: failed to connect to /'computers IP'/ (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)"

I have configured the Apache server on ports 80 and 433 and the Android app is connecting to "computers ip"/databasename, not "localhost". The code used for the use sign-ups is present below.
I have reviewed the code multiple times but cannot locate why the connection fails to establish

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.baidar.androidChatter.interfacer.Manager;
import com.baidar.androidChatter.serve.MessagingService;


public class SigningUp extends Activity {

    private static final int FILL_ALL_FIELDS = 0;
    protected static final int TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS = 1;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_FAILED = 9;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED = 3;
    private static final int SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL = 4;
    protected static final int USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT = 5;


    //private static final String SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_FAILED = "0";
    private static final String SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL = "1";
    private static final String SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED = "2";



    private EditText usernameText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private EditText eMailText;
    private EditText passwordAgainText;
    private Manager imService;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
            // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder)service).getService();  


        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
            // see this happen.
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(SigningUp.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    



            setContentView(R.layout.signingup);
            setTitle("Sign up");

            // Added to test a stack overflow addition
            bindService(new Intent(SigningUp.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            Button signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_signUp);
            usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
            passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  
            passwordAgainText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordAgain);  
            eMailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

            signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {                       
                    if (usernameText.length() > 0 &&        
                        passwordText.length() > 0 && 
                        passwordAgainText.length() > 0 &&
                        eMailText.length() > 0
                        )
                    {
                        //TODO check email address is valid

                        if (passwordText.getText().toString().equals(passwordAgainText.getText().toString())){

                            if (usernameText.length() >= 5 && passwordText.length() >= 5) {

                                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                                        String result = new String();
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            Log.d("problem", "The value of result is " + result.toString());

                                            result = imService.signUpUser(usernameText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    passwordText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    eMailText.getText().toString());

                                            handler.post(new Runnable(){

                                                public void run() {
                                                    // Added the "result != null &&" to the if 
                                                    if (result != null && result.equals(SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL)) { 
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_successfull, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (result != null && result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED)){
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_username_crashed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED);
                                                    }
                                                    else  //if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_FAILED)) 
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        //showDialog(SIGN_UP_FAILED);
                                                    }           
                                                }

                                            });
                                        }

                                    };
                                    thread.start();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.username_and_password_length_short, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //showDialog(USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }                           
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_type_same_password_in_password_fields, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //showDialog(TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS);
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.signup_fill_all_fields, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //showDialog(FILL_ALL_FIELDS);

                    }               
                }           
            });

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {                       
                    finish();                   
                }               
            });


        }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {       

        switch (id) 
        {
            case TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS:         
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_type_same_password_in_password_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();          
            case FILL_ALL_FIELDS:               
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_fill_all_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_FAILED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_failed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_username_crashed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_successfull)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })        
                .create();  
            case USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SigningUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.username_and_password_length_short)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            default:
                return null;

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        bindService(new Intent(SigningUp.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem: I was accessing (computers IP)/database when I should have been accessing (computers IP):port#/database, then add that port to the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after a while I found out that the android device believes that HE is the localhost and won't be able to connect to my computer's localhost server directly.. Try connecting to your own computer's IP instead of localhost. Took me an entire afternoon to figure out

EDIT : After searching a little I found out the article that saved me :
[Android connection to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811789/android-connection-to-localhost)

Comment: I have already set it up to connect to my computers IP. In the Android app it is connecting to "computers ip"/databasename

Comment: i found the problem, I was accessing http://(computers IP)/database when I should have been accessing http://(computers IP):port#/database , then add that port to the firewall and good to go