# Android Studio internet connection

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to connect to localhost on Android Studio

I tried : localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.2:8080

But I'm still getting the same response:

```
failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I found online ([Android connection to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811789/android-connection-to-localhost)) that in eclipse you should first bind the ip in eclipse settings.

But I can't figure out how to do the same in Android Studio

Comment: yes.. actually I'm trying to figure out how to use a real device right now... any good links?

Comment: You can't connect to your localhost using a real device.

Comment: OK - so I'll continue to use an emulator- but what should I do with this error message ?

Comment: I did mention in my answer below how you can use the real device to connect with your localhost. The error message is coming probably because the address you are trying to use is unreachable.

Comment: I tried an external URL and it seems to work fine. So the problem is indeed restricted only to localhost. Localhost is reachable via web browser.. But I'll try what you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to your localhost (127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2) using a real device. An easy solution is to make sure that your computer and android device are connected to the same network(WiFi / Host a hotspot) and then use the computer's IP Address to conect.