# Connection of Android Studio with localhost timed out

Tags: java, android, localhost, wamp

I have connected my Android App to WAMP server and I am running it on my mobile phone but each time I run the app, it gives the error:

> Exception: failed to connect to /192.168.1.5 (port 9090): connect
>   failed:   ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

I am giving this URL:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.5:9090/phpmysql.php";
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811789/android-connection-to-localhost) too but wasn't much helpful.

Comment: Have you tested that your php service is working properly?

Comment: Yes, I did. I opened the php file in the browser and tried to retrieve some data from my db and everything worked fine there.

Comment: your  phone also should connect to with same wifi, if server is local

Comment: Both the phone and the laptop are connected to the same WiFi.

Comment: open http://192.168.1.5:9090/phpmysql.php  in your browser and check if works

Answer (score 0):

Use 10.0.2.2 for emulator.
I think the url you are using is creating problems.

If it doesn't fix this error, try resetting the adb connection by force closing it from task manager and restarting the emulator. Also the wamp server should be running and should be accessible from your local browser.