# ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) on a server with authentication

Tags: android, authentication, download, httpclient, httpresponse

here is my download code:

```
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(downloadListHttpGet
                    .get(index));
            InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    memoryDirectory + fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                    output.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

This code works fine, but with authenticated server, after almost 40 seconds from download starting, I get "ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)" exception. I think it happens in "input.read(data)" part. I searched a lot!!! Some guys tell it is the server fault. It might be true but I have to resolve this problem in client side. I tried to run new thread in "catch" block but there is a problem: when exception occurs, it doesn't go to "catch" block immediately, it takes almost 2 minutes. I tried this solution :
[Getting "SocketException : Connection reset by peer" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `new DefaultHttpClient()` try to use this class `getHttpClient()`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    public static int ConnectionTimeoutInSeconds = 45;
    public static boolean DisableSSLcertificateCheck = true;

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    public static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        try {

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

            // Turn off stale checking.  Our connections break all the time anyway,
            // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
            HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);

            // Default connection and socket timeout of 20 seconds.  Tweak to taste.
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, ConnectionTimeoutInSeconds * 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, ConnectionTimeoutInSeconds * 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

            // Don't handle redirects -- return them to the caller.  Our code
            // often wants to re-POST after a redirect, which we must do ourselves.
            HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);

            SSLSocketFactory mySSLSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();

            // disable ssl check on debug
            if (DisableSSLcertificateCheck ) {
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);
                mySSLSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
                mySSLSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
            }

            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", mySSLSocketFactory, 443));
            ClientConnectionManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

}
```

It handles SSL, enable you to ignore the SSL certificate and allows you to change the timeouts manually. 
I would start with "disable ssl check" and set timeout to 90 (sec).

Another way you might try to authenticate is the same as Bing search API authentication works (you need to download and include commons-codec-1.9.jar):

```
public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=pinhassi";

        String accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

        URL url = null;
        url = new URL(bingUrl);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
        InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        String res = readStream(response);
        Log.d(TAG, res);
        //conn.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: thanks. I do not use KeyStore in my code. My authentication is like this: httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token) and then I pass httpGet to httpclient.execute(). What should I do?

Comment: I don't know about GlobalData either. Please help me.

Comment: I removed the GlobalData and set it as variable "DisableSSLcertificateCheck".

Comment: I removed the GlobalData and set it as variable "DisableSSLcertificateCheck". Ignore the KeyStore param, just call the static method getHttpClient(). About the header - i think your problem might be there. I don't know what kind of authorization your server expects you to send and how: maybe you should send it as post param and not get? maybe as get param, in the form of www.xyz.com/?Authorization="Bearer". Try to figure it out first...