# react native android recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, react-native, axios

my network request fail with this error `recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`

according to this it seems related to `keep-alive`
[Getting "SocketException : Connection reset by peer" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)

But I can't set this on apisauce. It looks like apisauce uses axios internally. On axios this line seems setting the `keep-alive`
`httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true })`
https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config

But what is http? and where should i import it.
Or is there any other thing I am missing ?

`recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you got the solution?