# HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-proguard

> **Facing issue while using pro-guard** **against retrofit**

```
 HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET
 (Connection reset by peer)
```

I know this question has been already asked, but this error which i am facing is from other scenario...
Found links related to this error but i get doesn't  any proper solution.

[Getting "SocketException : Connection reset by peer" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1027

I use `Retrofit` `HTTP client` for api calling by using body request.

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

**My Client**

```
public static OkHttpClient getClient() {

        if (client == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            RequestInterceptor m1RequestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor();
            client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(m1RequestInterceptor)
                    .build();
        }
        return client;
    }
```

**Pro-guard rules**

```
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

**Issue :** When i hit request to server for response for single time will work perfect and got response from server, but when i hit multiple request at a time (more than 5 request to server) getting `HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`

> **Note:** Works perfectly fine without proguard , but while i add proguard i got this above issue

**I also got this link** --> https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1027 --> But it was close and didn't get any solution for that.

Comment: Most POST requests require a slash `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: @ViktorStojanov please read  my Question properly , the issue when i getting is while i use pro proguard  and other thing is with proguard single request are working perfectly  fine

Comment: @ND1010_ did you find any solution? I think this is a bug in OkHttp but they dont want accept and resolve it! I did server monitoring by tcpdump and it seems sometimes my request are not coming to server at all!