# flutter: cant access non ssl api after set proxy

Tags: flutter

i need to set proxy globally in my project, i did that with `flutter_socks_proxy` package.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SocksProxy.initProxy(
      proxy: 'SOCKS5 192.111.139.165:4145',
      onCreate: (client) {
        client.badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      });

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

it works but i have a problem, i can't access http (non ssl) api after set the proxy.

```
final url = Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London');
final response = await http.get(url);
print(response.body);
```

this is the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer
```

it works fine with https apis.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the allowance of Clear Text Traffic, which in this case is the HTTP, you can allow it by the following steps:

**For Android**:

1. Navigate to the this file: `./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
2. In the proprites of the `application` tag, add this property: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

The final file should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

**For IOS**:

1. Navigate to the this file: `./ios/Runner/info.plist`
2. Add the following key-value pair:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Note:**

You may need to run `flutter clean` after applying the above changes to ensure that the native files compiles again with a fresh run.

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Check this one and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227387/11217945