# dart - http.get not returning a response for HTTP URL

Tags: flutter, dart, http, get

I am trying to do a super simple `http.get` in dart with Flutter but I am not getting a result, it gets blocked.

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit1:** after a minute of waiting, it got to the catch the following exception:

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'worldtimeapi.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

My code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void getTime() async {
    try{
      var url = Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London');
      // var url = Uri.parse('https://catfact.ninja/fact');
      final response = await http.get(url);   //await causes a block forever. nothing happens afterwards
      // Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(response);
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you `print(await http.get(url))`?

Comment: Try changing the `http` to `https`.

`https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London`

Comment: Can you please share the output of the print inside the `catch` block?

Comment: You must get *something*? What is `response`  when you print it? Alternatively, what is `e` when it gets printed?

Comment: after a minute it got to the catch : SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'worldtimeapi.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)  ill check it .!!!

Comment: ok, im not sure what i did, probably its the solution below . but now it works!!!

Comment: @eyalgromzin Can you please check the new answer and accept it? it is the same as the previous accepted answer but referring to the original answer by me because the first one got deleted due to duplication.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of not allowing the Clear Text Traffic, which in this case is the HTTP, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403028/11217945) to get the steps for allowing it.