# java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, ubuntu, ip, netty

Till yesterday my server was working fine, after sudden 500 disconnection of clients my Netty Server shows  **java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer**  error  while client is connecting. Server is running on 
Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1 LTS Edition

JRE 7

and netty 3.5.11

Why i am getting this error ?

Is this occur due to any OS problem something like IP blocker?

"I have read that this exception occur while trying to write something to a closed channel. But in my case I don't know how channel is being closed. Channel is closing after a message is being sent, all other functionalities works fine till yesterday"
I have set the u limit already.

Comment: I think by any reason you are not able to connect to remote server, it could be any reason eiyher you are behind firewel or your virtual private network is not giving permisiion to read write check your permision first

Comment: You will have to look at the other application. A RST means the socket was open at certain point, but the remote end no longer has it open for some reason. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: Are you really getting this while connecting, or while doing I/O?

Comment: @EJP I get this error after a message is being sent(Yes doing IO)

Answer (score 1):

> "I have read that this exception occur while trying to write something to a closed channel.

No you haven't. You have read, or you should have read, that this can happen as a result of writing to a *connection* that has already been closed *by the peer.* it isn't at all the same thing. If you read what you said anywhere you should cease using that source.