# hadoop while running my program following message displayed. what does it mean?

Tags: java, hadoop

I was running hadoop program and I got following message. what does it mean?
should I need to worry about this message?

```
INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:531)
14/12/15 16:39:36 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block BP-1435953827-192.168.33.125-1417678953955:blk_1073749097_67711 in pipeline 192.168.33.199:50010, 192.168.33.125:50010, 192.168.33.123:50010: bad datanode 192.168.33.199:50010
```

Comment: Ahmad, do you know reason?

Comment: Does this help (it looks similar problem) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718900/exception-in-createblockoutputstream-when-copying-data-into-hdfs

Comment: no, Kabir that's different problem.

Comment: actually, I don't got any problem. As mentioned error has been recovered by other node.

Comment: I think one of your data node is running bad state or on low disk space.

Comment: This shows that one of the data node is not available.

Comment: I think one of the datanode failed during data copy on hdfs. so, data is recovered from other node.