# java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available in Spark on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm getting this weird exception. I'm using Spark 1.6.0 on Hadoop 2.6.4 and submitting Spark job on YARN cluster.

```
16/07/23 20:05:21 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception  for block BP-532134798-128.110.152.143-1469321545728:blk_1073741865_1041
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:867)
16/07/23 20:49:09 ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=4719626006875125240, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=81 cap=81]}} to ms0440.utah.cloudlab.us/128.110.152.175:58944; closing connection
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

I was getting this error when running on Hadoop 2.6.0 and thought the exception might be kind of a bug like [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-8475) but after even changing this to Hadoop 2.6.4 I'm getting the same error. There is not any memory problem, my cluster is good with HDFS and memory. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483004/hadoop-while-running-my-program-following-message-displayed-what-does-it-mean) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718900/exception-in-createblockoutputstream-when-copying-data-into-hdfs) but no luck.

Note: 1. I'm using Apache Hadoop and Spark not any CDH/HDP. 2. I'm able to copy data in HDFS and even able to execute another job on this cluster.

Comment: i get similar issues. Did you find a solution ?  @ChikuMiku

Comment: @harpribot not yet.

Comment: I think Hadoop version was the issue. No issues in 2.7.2, which I updated later; Also, check your firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions of dfs directory:

```
find /path/to/dfs -group root
```

In general, the user permission group is `hdfs`.
Since I started HDFS service with root user, some dfs block file with `root` permissions was generated.

I solved the problem after change to right permissions:

```
sudo chown -R hdfs:hdfs /path/to/dfs
```