# submit local spark job to emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

im following the amazon doc on submiting spark jobs to emr cluster
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/

after following the instructions, with the frecuent troubleshoot it fails due to unresolved address with a message similar to.

> ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   ip-172-32-1-231.us-east-2.compute.internal    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)

as i saw that the IP it was trying to resolve was the master node one, i changed it with **sed** to the public one in the configurations files (the ones obtained from the /etc/hadoop/conf directory in the master node). but then the error is connecting to the datanodes

> INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/172.32.1.41:50010]
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1404)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1357)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:587)
>   19/02/08 13:54:58 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning BP-1960505320-172.32.1.231-1549632479324:blk_1073741907_1086

finally i tried the same solution as this question = 
[Spark HDFS Exception in createBlockOutputStream while uploading resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932412/spark-hdfs-exception-in-createblockoutputstream-while-uploading-resource-file)

which was to add to the hdfs-site.xml file the following:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

but the error persist as unresolved address exception

```
19/02/08 13:58:06 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1357)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:587)
```

could somebody help me set up spark in my local machine to do spark-submit to remote EMR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides following the answer on the linked question, you should also add the (public) IPs and (private) DNS of the worker nodes to your **/etc/hosts** file.