# QuickFix C++ Socket Error Connection Reset By Peer?

Tags: quickfix

I getting "Socket Error: Connection reset by peer." while trying to login to the server. 
 Below are the logs:-

<20141024-08:20:25.556, FIX.4.4:CMSPCFX->CNX, outgoing> 

(8=FIX.4.49=11235=A34=149=CMSPCFX50=CMSPCFX52=20141024-08:20:25.53356=CNX98=1108=30141=Y553=XXXXXXX554=XXXXXXX10=028)

<20141024-08:20:25.556, FIX.4.4:CMSPCFX->CNX, event> 

(Initiated logon request)

<20141024-08:20:25.800, FIX.4.4:CMSPCFX->CNX, event>

(Socket Error: Connection reset by peer.)

<20141024-08:20:25.800, FIX.4.4:CMSPCFX->CNX, event> 

(Disconnecting)

Below is the config:-


[DEFAULT]

ConnectionType=initiator

DefaultApplVerID=FIX.4.4

FileStorePath=./FIX_LOG_DIR

FileLogPath=./FIX_LOG_DIR_LOG

ResetOnLogon=Y

ResetOnLogout=Y

ResetOnDisconnect=Y

[SESSION]

BeginString=FIX.4.4

SenderCompID=CMSPCFX

SenderSubID=CMSPCFX

TargetCompID=CNX

StartTime=00:00:00

EndTime=00:00:00

ReconnectInterval=30

HeartBtInt=30

SocketConnectHost=integration.currenex.com

SocketConnectPort=443

DataDictionary=./Config/spec/FIX44.xml

TransportDataDictionary=./Config/spec/FIX44.xml

ScreenLogEvent = Y

ScreenLogShowIncoming = Y

ScreenLogShowOutgoing = Y

ScreenLogShowHeartBeats = Y

FileLogHeartbeats = Y

FileIncludeMilliseconds=Y 

FileIncludeTimeStampForMessages=Y

TimeZone = America/New_York

UserName=XXXXXXXXXXX

Password = XXXXXXXXX

Is it due to tag 52 having UTC time value?

Comment: You should ask your counterparty to tell you why they closed the connection.  It could be lots of things, including bad username or password, wrong FIX version, bad or missing other parameters....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean . Check your network connection. This might be at the network level also, so you would need to check all avenues. `Is it due to tag 52 having UTC time value?` don't think so. Connection willn't be dropped in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was due to network.