# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, asp.net, openssl, azure-mobile-services

I use following code to call an Azure mobile backend API in my Android app,

```
try {
    mobileClient.invokeApi("CustomTransaction", senderToCheck,
        Boolean.class, new ApiOperationCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Boolean result,
        Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (error == null) {
                CheckSender(result);
            } else {
                dial.dismiss();
                Crouton.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "Eror Occured with service",
                    Style.ALERT).show();
            }
        }
    });
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Other information:

```
CustomTransaction - API Controller name;
senderToCheck - JSON parsable data transfer object;
Boolean.class - return type; and 4th parameter is the callback method
```

All objects are JSON parsable and this worked like several days ago.

So this API call/Azure call always times out giving a [What does "connection reset by peer" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) ,SSLHandShakeExceptionand and most of the time Connect gets Timed out.

Main cause for the problem is com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.

I tried re-publishing my asp.net web app several times but it never hits controller action where my debugger point is placed when debugging the service call remotely.

I checked if my service is down, found it is up & running then checked Azure management portal logs, found out traceApi messages of some controller action methods. and of SQL Cpu usages and Data out packet sizes., but I never gets a proper reply from anywhere to solve this problem for two weeks now.

In case,if I am correct, think the solution for this problem lies in http://www.webapper.com/blog/index.php/2007/02/09/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception/ but Im not pretty sure on doing it.

Please advise me on getting this fixed

Comment: What is the server name, and what is the URL you are using to access the resource?

Comment: Thanks heaps jww, but this started to work after several hours, thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you running in the free tier?  If so, you may have gone over your quota (which would explain why it worked later). If you upgrade to Basic, you won't have these quota violations.

Comment: nah I'm on premium actually, this happens when I am trying from my Home only, I think this has got something to do with my router model. Because I got other people from Australia and UK in my dev team they are not facing any of these issues. crazy...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "connection reset by peer" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean)