# RabbitMQ Error: fwrite(): send of 12 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I'm using the RabbitMQ Library [videlalvaro/php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) inside a [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/) application and I've started getting the following error:

```
fwrite(): send of 12 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer"
```

Can anyone suggest anything that might be causing this?

Comment: Just some minor formatting tweaks.

Comment: @Marwan if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 5):

> "Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying, leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly polite TCP/IP converseur. ([From other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434506/816449))

So you can't do anything about it, it is the issue of the server.

But you could use `try .. catch` block to handle that exception:

```
try {
    $msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Setting prefetch count to 1 is working for me as I don't care little performance tradeoff with stability.

```
$channel->basic_qos(0, 1, false);
```

syntax:

```
basic_qos($prefetch_size, $prefetch_count, $a_global);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. This case could resolved this problem. You should call this method in your method 'execute' in ClassNameConsumer class.

For php lang.

```
/**
 * Resolved problem - Connection reset by peer
 * @param AMQPMessage $msg
 */
public function keepAlive(AMQPMessage $msg)
{
    if (!isset($this->message->delivery_info['channel'])) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var AMQPChannel $channel */
    $channel = $msg->delivery_info['channel'];

    $pkt = new AMQPWriter();
    $pkt->write_octet(8);
    $pkt->write_short(0);
    $pkt->write_long(0);
    $pkt->write_octet(0xCE);

    $channel->getConnection()->write($pkt->getvalue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using the php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle on a Symfony project, I was getting the error 'Connection reset by peer' very often, the problem was related to the prefetch size, so by limiting the prefetch size I got rid of this error.

On the consumer configuration you need to add the line below:

```
qos_options: {prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false}
```

You will have something like this:

```
consumers:
    consumer_name:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: {name: 'consumer-name', type: direct}
        queue_options:    {name: 'consumer-name'}
        callback:         consumer_name_service
        qos_options:      {prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false}
```