# Neo4j Error: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: neo4j

I keep getting this error at least once a day but I'm not sure what is causing it and how I can try to prevent it. We are running Neo4j 2.2.3 and we use the REST API because we connect to it using nodejs. If there is any other info let me know and I can provide it.

Thank you for the help.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:234)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeServletOutputStream.flush(TeeServletOutputStream.java:85)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.flush(WebComponent.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.flush(ContainerResponse.java:146)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172)
    ... 55 more
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:234)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeServletOutputStream.flush(TeeServletOutputStream.java:85)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.flush(WebComponent.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.flush(ContainerResponse.java:146)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172)
    ... 55 more
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:234)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeServletOutputStream.flush(TeeServletOutputStream.java:85)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.flush(WebComponent.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.flush(ContainerResponse.java:146)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172)
    ... 55 more
```

EDIT 9/18/15

So it seems to have been an issue with the Neo4j Version I was using. I can still see the error in the logs but it no longer crashes the Database.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace indicates that a [peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) (in this case, a client) dropped the connection while neo4j was being asked to authorize a request.

If you are not seeing any issues in the neo4j DB, I think this type of error can be ignored on the server side.

But you may want to check your clients to see if their code is inappropriately dropping the connection or crashing while making REST requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This error is causing the server to go down and there is a slight delay before a new master is elected. During this time (although short like a second or two) it causes requests to fail which isnt good and which is why im trying to figure out a way to prevent it from happening. Im not seeing any errors on our nodejs server that would cause the connection to be dropped but I will continue to keep an eye on that just in case.

Answer (score 0):

As @cybersam mentioned in his answer, problem is with authorize a request.

You need to provide authorization header in your request

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html