# Getting an EOF exception while coverting bitmap to encoded string and then sending the encoded string using json object request

Tags: android, android-volley, eofexception

```
public void uploadImage(View v) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bp.compress((Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG), 100, stream);
    encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(),
            Base64.DEFAULT);

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(Finalize.this);
    System.out.println(encodedString);
    String url = "http://49.50.72.188/FoodAppWebService/Foodapp.asmx/UploadImage?img="
            + encodedString + "&MealId=" + mealId;

    JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    request.add(stringRequest);
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Is there any way I can avoid this exception I have not been able to find anything relevant to this and following is log file**

```
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681): com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:134)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readHeaders(HttpEngine.java:627)
11-21 10:58:41.111: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:580)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681):     ... 1 more
11-21 10:58:41.121: W/System.err(5681): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
11-21 10:58:41.131: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
11-21 10:58:41.131: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:140)
11-21 10:58:41.131: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
11-21 10:58:41.131: W/System.err(5681):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
11-21 10:58:41.131: W/System.err(5681):     ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a [connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean), which is basically the server puking on your data. Check to make sure that the server accepts the (potentially large amount of) data that you're transmitting.

Comment: can you give me a detailed solution for this like is it a server side problem??