# What is making "Connection Reset by Peer" happen in educational, restricted internet, environment?

Tags: ssh, filter, packet

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) mentions that "Connection Reset by Peer" means the server has sent an RST packet.  Is it possible that the computer you're trying to reach it from actually returned a fake RST packet to block the connection?  How can this be diagnosed?

Comment: more than likely it is either the gateway that is returning the reset and therefore restricting the internet or the dns server for your environment is returning an IP (no matter what host name is provided) for all requests that points to a server that simply resets all connections.

Comment: @dboals how do I diagnose that?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response had a family emergency. I would probably use wire shark to see what the transactions on the network where, but the first thing you could do is something like nslookup (linux/unix) to test to see what IP address is returned for any given domain.  If it is a local network IP odds are you are running into a dns issue. If it is the real IP address then depending on the service you are testing you could try using something like telnet to see what happens when you attempt to connect to the given service.