# Indy TCPServer is giving `Connection reset by peer` error when client connects

Tags: delphi, debugging, tcp, firemonkey, indy10

I am trying to create a TCP server using Delphi firemonkey application.

My resource file `Unit1.fmx` is given below.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnActivate = FormShow
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 504.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 248.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label1'
  end
  object TCPServer: TIdTCPServer
    Bindings = <>
    DefaultPort = 0
    OnAfterBind = TCPServerAfterBind
    OnConnect = TCPServerOnConnect
    OnExecute = TCPserverExecute
    Left = 560
    Top = 184
  end
end
```

My code file is given here.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Platform,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdContext,
  IdSocketHandle, IdUDPServer, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, Windows;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TCPserverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure TCPServerOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure TCPServerAfterBind(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TMyLoggingService = class(TInterfacedObject, IFMXLoggingService)
  public
    procedure Log(const Format: string; const Params: array of const);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyLoggingService: IFMXLoggingService;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMyLoggingService.Log(const Format: string; const Params: array of const);
begin
  // do whatever you want...
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format));
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding : TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  MyLoggingService := TMyLoggingService.Create;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService( IFMXLoggingService ) then
    TPlatformServices.Current.RemovePlatformService( IFMXLoggingService );
  // register my service
  TPlatformServices.Current.AddPlatformService( IFMXLoggingService, MyLoggingService );
  TCPServer.DefaultPort := 16000;
  TCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := TCPServer.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '127.0.0.1';
  Binding.Port := 16000;
  //if Assigned(MyLoggingService) then
  MyLoggingService.Log('FormCreate!',[]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TCPServer.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.TCPServerAfterBind(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyLoggingService.Log('After Bind',[]);
end;

procedure TForm1.TCPServerOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  MyLoggingService.Log('Recieved Connection From Client ',[]);
end;

procedure TForm1.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var
C : String;
begin
 C:= AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn();
 //if Assigned(MyLoggingService) then
 MyLoggingService.Log('TserverExecute !',[]);

 MyLoggingService.Log('Recived Data !',[C]);
 if C = 'TESTSTRING' then
 begin
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Writeln('SENT');
 end;


end;

end.
```

My problem is In the system log where I am logging my messages this is what I get.

```
Debug Output: FormCreate! Process Project1.exe (3340)
Debug Output: After Bind Process Project1.exe (3340)
Debug Output: Recieved Connection From Client  Process Project1.exe (3340)
First chance exception at $759BC42D. Exception class EIdSocketError with message
'Socket Error # 10054
Connection reset by peer.'.
Process Project1.exe (3340)
```

[connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean). My question is why is this happening with my code ? What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?

At the remote end I have a very simple python script which is given below.

```
import socket

# Set up a TCP/IP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect as client to a selected server
# on a specified port
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',16000))

# Protocol exchange - sends and receives
data = 'TESTSTRING';
s.send(data.encode())
while True:
    resp = s.recv(1024)
    if resp == "": 
        print('NOTHING')
        break
    else:
        print(resp)
        break

# Close the connection when completed
s.close()
print("\ndone")
```

Comment: @Ken White - Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the server code.  The client is disconnecting on its end, and the *debugger* on the server side is simply detecting the exception that Indy raises to itself to handle the disconnect.  **This is normal behavior**.

There is, however, a problem with your client code.  On the server side, you are using `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()`, which is expecting the client to send a line of text delimited by a `LF` character (or a `CRLF` string).  But your client script is not sending that delimiter at all, so `ReadLn()` does not exit, and the server consequently does not call `TIdIOHandler.WriteLn()` to send a response.  On the client side, `s.recv()` is likely failing (since no response is being received) and the script ends, disconnecting the socket, causing `ReadLn()` on the server side to raise an exception back to `TIdTCPServer` so it can stop the thread close the socket.