# Android socket exception (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection-reset

I am trying to use Android's `VpnService` to forward packets to their original destination after i receive them. After writing data to the socket with the correct destination address, I am trying to get the response like this:

```
Socket socket = SocketChannel.open().socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipPacket.getDestinationIp(), ipPacket.getDstPort()));

ByteBuffer serverResponse = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535);
InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
int responseLength = socketInputStream.read(serverResponse.array());
```

However the line `int responseLength = socketInputStream.read(serverResponse.array());` is causing the following issue:

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

How can i fix this?

Comment: Tell the server on the other end (=the peer) not to close the connection :) ["what does reset by peer mean"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) Whatever the error causing this is, it's not in the few lines of code you show. How do you get that `Socket`? Did you `.close()` it or a stream attached to it earlier?

Comment: @zapl I have created the socket like this: `Socket socket = SocketChannel.open().socket();` and `socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipPacket.getDestinationIp(), ipPacket.getDstPort()));` where the destination IP and port are from the packet received by the VPN's `tun` interface

Comment: @EJP Sorry i am confused about what you are trying to say

Comment: OT but why are you using this bizarre mixture of NIO and streams and ByteBuffers and byte arrays? Make up your mind. Use one or the other. If you're a beginner in networking I would definitely use sockets and streams..

Comment: @EJP I was using `SocketChannel.open()` because my `protect()` method in `VpnService` wouldn't work without it. I have changed it and now it does work without errors. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Never mind, it seemed like it was working but apparently it is still giving the same error