# Why does connection pool size keep increasing with Golang HTTP client?

Tags: http, go, concurrency, web-crawler

I am basically making a health check crawler to a huge list of domains. I have a Golang script that creates ~256 routines that make requests to the list of domains. I am using the same client with the following transport configuration:

```
# init func
this.client = &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            ForceAttemptHTTP2:   true,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: TLSHandShakeTimeout,
            TLSClientConfig:     &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
            MaxConnsPerHost:     -1,
            DisableKeepAlives:   true,
        },
        Timeout: RequestTimeout,
    }
... 
# crawler func
req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(this.ctx, "GET", opts.Url, nil)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to create request")
}

res, err := this.client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer res.Body.Close()
...
```

I ran `netstat -anp  | wc -l` and can see over 2000+ connections with TIME_WAIT.

Comment: I think MaxConnsPerHost means something other than what you expect it to mean.

Comment: consider what MaxIdleConns does. https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/tune-the-go-http-client-for-high-performance/

you want something like MaxIdleConns 255 and MaxConnsPerHost 1

/// not sure... just reading the docs.

Comment: Even with MaxIdleConns=256, MaxConnsPerHost=1, I can see connections rising over 1000+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385692/limited-concurrent-connections-in-go

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774624/go-http-get-concurrency-and-connection-reset-by-peer/37813844#37813844

specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362012/657703

Comment: I am making requests to different hosts, not the same host.

Comment: What the state of 2000+ connections? TIME_WAIT?

Comment: Yes, TIME_WAIT, but is set MaxIdleConnsPerHost=-1 and I close the body

Comment: @Abe, the incorrect `MaxConnsPerHost` and `DisableKeepAlives` is used in your case. For more details, please refer to my answer. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @zangw please make sure to read my question carefully. This would make sense if you are making requests to the same host, HOWEVER, I am making requests to thousands of different hots. Which is why we do want to disable keep alives.

Comment: @Abe, Sorry for misunderstanding the question before. For your issue, my answer is updated, hope it could help you.

Answer (score 2):

The default number of goroutines per host for `http.Client` is 2. One is for the receiver and the other for the sender. So for thousands of domains, there could be thousands of goroutines here.

As the `DisableKeepAlives` is set to `true`, so the connection will be closed when the response of HTTP is done. The `TIME_WAIT` is the normal TCP state after closing a connection.

However, the default timeout of `TIME_WAIT` state on Linux is 60 seconds. The huge number of `TIME_WAIT` states could cause the server (such as probe/crawler) connection issue.

---

In order to solve the `TIME_WAIT` issue. The [`SO_LINGER`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) option could help. It disables the default TCP delayed-close behavior, which sends the RST to the peer when the connection is closed. And it would remove the `TIME_wAIT` state of the TCP connection.

More discussion could be found here [When is TCP option SO_LINGER (0) required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/when-is-tcp-option-so-linger-0-required)

Sample

```golang
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
        Control: func(network, address string, conn syscall.RawConn) error {
            var opterr error
            if err := conn.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
                l := &syscall.Linger{}
                opterr = syscall.SetsockoptLinger(int(fd), unix.SOL_SOCKET, unix.SO_LINGER, l)
            }); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return opterr
        },
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: dialer.DialContext,
        },
    }
```

---

Moreover, here is another `SO_LINGER` use case in [EaseProbe](https://github.com/megaease/easeprobe/blob/main/probe/http/http.go#L120). It is a simple, standalone, and lightweight tool that can do health/status checking.

Comment: @Adrian, my bad, just copy from my sample codes. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am already closing the body

Comment: @Abe, I reproduce your issue. and fix it through correct the parameter of `Transport`

Comment: This is incorrect for crawling different hosts which does require to disable keep alives. Your example only tests a single host.

Comment: Just post anther option with `SO_LINGER`, hope it could solve your issue @Abe