# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference with bigger data

Tags: http, go, nullpointerexception, goroutine, predictionio

I am working on a recommendation engine with Apache Prediction IO. Before the event server i have an GO api that listens events from customer and importer. In a particular case when customer uses importer i collect the imported identitys and i send in a json from importer api to GO api. As an example if user imports a csv that contains 45000 data, i send those 45000 identity to  GO api in a json like `{"barcodes":[...]}`. Prediction IO event server wants data in a particular shape.

```
type ItemEvent struct {
    Event      string              `json:"event"`
    EntityType string              `json:"entityType"`
    EntityId   string              `json:"entityId"`
    Properties map[string][]string `json:"properties"`
    EventTime  time.Time           `json:"eventTime"`
}


type ItemBulkEvent struct {
    Event     string    `json:"event"`
    Barcodes []string  `json:"barcodes"`
    EventTime time.Time `json:"eventTime"`
}
```

`ItemEvent` is the final data that i will send to event server from GO Api. `ItemBulkEvent` is the data that i receive from importer api.

```
func HandleItemBulkEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var itemBulk model.ItemBulkEvent
    err := decode(r,&itemBulk)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("handleitembulkevent -> ",err)
        util.RespondWithError(w,400,err.Error())
    }else {
        var item model.ItemEvent
        item.EventTime = itemBulk.EventTime; item.EntityType = "item"; item.Event = itemBulk.Event
        itemList := make([]model.ItemEvent,0,50)
        for index, barcode := range itemBulk.Barcodes{
            item.EntityId = barcode
            if (index > 0 && (index % 49) == 0){
                itemList = append(itemList, item)
                go sendBulkItemToEventServer(w,r,itemList)
                itemList = itemList[:0]
            }else if index == len(itemBulk.Barcodes) - 1{
                itemList = append(itemList, item)
                itemList = itemList[:( (len(itemBulk.Barcodes) - 1) % 49)]
                go sendBulkItemToEventServer(w,r,itemList) // line 116 
                itemList = itemList[:0]
            } else{
                itemList = append(itemList, item)
            }
        }
        util.RespondWithJSON(w,200,"OK")
    }
}
```

`HandleItemBulkEvent` is a handler function for bulk updates. In this step i should mention about prediction io's batch uploads. Via rest api prediction io event server takes 50 event per request. So i created a list with 50 cap and an item. I used same item and just changed identity part(barcode) in every turn and added to list. In every 50. item i used a handler function that sends that list to event server and after that cleaned the list so on.

```
func sendBulkItemToEventServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, itemList []model.ItemEvent){
    jsonedItem,err := json.Marshal(itemList)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln("err marshalling -> ",err.Error())
    }
    // todo: change url to event server url
    resp, err2 := http.Post(fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:7070/batch/events.json?accessKey=%s",
        r.Header.Get("Authorization")),
        "application/json",
        bytes.NewBuffer(jsonedItem))
    if err2 != nil{
        log.Fatalln("err http -> " , err.Error()) // line 141
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

`sendBulkItemToEventServer` function marshals the incoming itemlist and makes an post request to prediction io's event server. In this part when i try with 5000+- item it does well but when i try with 45000 item application crashes with below error.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xc05938]

goroutine 620 [running]:
api-test/service.sendBulkItemToEventServer(0x1187860, 0xc00028e0e0, 0xc00029c200, 0xc00011c000, 0x31, 0x32)
        /home/kadirakinkorkunc/Desktop/playground/recommendation-engine/pio_api/service/CollectorService.go:141 +0x468
created by api-test/service.HandleItemBulkEvent
        /home/kadirakinkorkunc/Desktop/playground/recommendation-engine/pio_api/service/CollectorService.go:116 +0x681

Debugger finished with exit code 0
```

Any idea how can i solve this problem?

**edit**: as Burak Serdar mentioned in the answers, i fixed the err, err2 confusion and the data race problem by using marshalling before send. Now it gives me the real error(res,err2) i guess.

```
2020/08/03 15:11:55 err http ->  Post "http://localhost:7070/batch/events.json?accessKey=FJbGODbGzxD-CoLTdwTN2vwsuEEBJEZc4efrSUc6ekV1qUYAWPu5anDTyMGDoNq1": read tcp 127.0.0.1:54476->127.0.0.1:7070: read: connection reset by peer
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: Please mention which code is at line #141.

Comment: I declared those lines as a comment in the code, i guess you missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your program. The runtime error is because you are checking if `err2` is not nil, but then you're printing `err`, not `err2`. `err` is nil, thus the runtime error.

This means `err2` is not nil, so you should see what that error is.

You mentioned you are sending messages in batches of 50, but that implementation is wrong. You add elements to the `itemList`, then start a goroutine with that `itemList`, then truncate it and start filling again. That is a data race, and your goroutines will see the `itemList` instances that are being modified by the handler. Instead of truncating, simply create a new `itemList` when you submit one to the goroutine, so each goroutine can have their own copy.

If you want to keep using the same slice, you can marshal the slice, and then pass the JSON message to the goroutine instead of the slice.

Comment: Thanks, i did what you say. Now it gives me the real cause i guess. I edited the question if you want to take a look.

Comment: It looks like the receiving end of those requests has a problem. Check the logs for that server. Maybe you're overloading it with many concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is the one sent by the server you are making the request to. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774624/go-http-get-concurrency-and-connection-reset-by-peer#:%7E:text=The%20message%20connection%20reset%20by,connections%2C%20or%20reconnecting%20too%20fast.) out for understanding more about the error.

Most likely the following for loop

> ```
> for index, barcode := range itemBulk.Barcodes{
> ```

has too many iterations and because you are using separate go routines for creating the request, all the requests happen concurrently which either overloads the server or makes it deliberately close the connection.