# Getting file errors after creating python script titled ssl.py

Tags: python, macos, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssl-common.py", line 14, in 
    s = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=dst[0])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in **init**
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

I am getting the above errors when I try to run the below script on my Mac. I have reinstalled openssl through homebrew, as well as through pip

```
import socket
import ssl
import OpenSSL.crypto as crypto

dst = ('1.2.3.4',443)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ret = s.connect_ex(dst)
if ret == 0 :
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    s = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=dst[0])

    # get certificate
    cert_bin = s.getpeercert(True)
    x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1,cert_bin)
    print(x509.get_subject().CN)
else :
    print "socket.connect_ex returned ", ret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

It seems like a problem on where you want to connect. Check your connectivity by pinging and etc.

Please do check this out: [What does "connection reset by peer" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean#1434506)

Comment: I am trying to suppress the error for a site that isn't currently on right now (trying to loop through a bunch of IPs), but I get the above errors