# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I was trying to make a simple chat room using Sockets in python3. When I ran my server on my localhost and set up clients using multiple terminals, everything went fine. When I tried to connect to the server (which was hosted on my system) by another system connected to same LAN network, this error came out.

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

When I tried to reconnect from second system again and again it gave me another error

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This is my server.py

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, socket
from threading import Thread

HOST = "192.168.157.206"
PORT = 3000

addresses = {}
clients = {}

def Connections():
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print("{} is connected!!".format(addr))
        client.send(("Welcome to Chat Room. Type {quit} to exit. Enter your name: ").encode("utf-8"))
        addresses[client] = addr
        Thread(target = ClientConnection, args=(client, )).start()

def ClientConnection(client):
    name = client.recv(BufferSize).decode("utf-8")
    client.send(("Hello {}".format(name)).encode("utf-8"))
    message = ("{} has joined the chat..").format(name)
    Broadcast(message.encode("utf-8"))
    clients[client] = name
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BufferSize).decode("utf-8")
        if msg != "quit":
            Broadcast(msg.encode("utf-8"), name + ": ")
        else:
            message = ("{} has left the chat.").format(clients[client])
            Broadcast(message.encode("utf-8"))
            client.send(("Will see you soon..").encode("utf-8"))
            del clients[client]
            break

def Broadcast(msg, name = ""):
    for sockets in clients:
        sockets.send(name.encode("utf-8") + msg)

server = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
try:
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
except OSError:
    print("Server Busy")
BufferSize = 1024

server.listen(5)
print("Waiting for Connections... ")
AcceptThread = Thread(target=Connections)
AcceptThread.start()
AcceptThread.join()
server.close()
```

This is my client.py

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, socket
from threading import Thread

HOST = input("Enter Host IP: ")
PORT = eval(input("Enter Port No: "))
BufferSize = 1024

def Recieve():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(BufferSize).decode("utf-8")
            print(msg)
        except OSError:
            break

def Send():
    while True:
        msg = input()
        if msg == "quit":
            client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
            client.close()
            break
        else:
            client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))

client = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))

RecieveThread = Thread(target=Recieve).start()
SendThread = Thread(target=Send).start()
```

Please tell me where I went wrong. I went through this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean?rq=1). But I cannot figure out where to correct this in my code. 
Thanks in advance.