# requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError connection broken

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm importing data from API using multithreathing as:

```
def importdata(data, auth_token):
    # # ---  Get data from Keros API --
    hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    urlApi = 'http://...&offset=0&limit=1'
    responsedata = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    if responsedata.ok:
        num_of_records = int(math.ceil(responsedata.json()['total']))
        value_limit = 249 # Number of records per page.
        num_of_pages = num_of_records / value_limit
        print num_of_records
        print num_of_pages
        pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages-1)]
        #pages = [i for i in range(0, 3)]
        datarALL = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_pages) as executor:
            futh = [(executor.submit(getdata, page, hed, value_limit)) for page in pages]
            for data in as_completed(futh):
                datarALL = datarALL + data.result()
        return datarALL
    else:
        return None


def getdata(page,hed,limit):
    is_valid = True
    value_offset = page * limit
    value_limit = limit  #limit of records allowed per page
    datarALL = []
    url = 'http://...&offset={0}&limit={1}'.format(value_offset,value_limit)
    responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    if responsedata.status_code == 200:  #200 for successful call
        responsedata = responsedata.text
        jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
        if "results" in jsondata:
            if jsondata["results"]:
                datarALL = datarALL + jsondata["results"]
    print "page {} finished".format(page)
    return datarALL
```

When I set:

`pages = [i for i in range(0, 3)]` **it works** with no problems.

But when I try

```
pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages-1)]
```

It generate this error:

```
page 317 finished
page 240 finished
page 15 finished
page 12 finished
page 350 finished
page 16 finished
page 288 finished
page 18 finished
page 17 finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/import.py", line 84, in importdata
    datarALL = datarALL + data.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 455, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 63, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scripts/import.py", line 54, in getdata
    responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 662, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 827, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 752, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I'm not sure why this happens and why it gives me connection broken?
Any idea why it doesn't work?

Is there a way to actually get detail of what is broken? for example which specific `url` caused the problem etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

The log is clear that the connection between the script and the server got broken. And the reason is `Connection reset by peer`. If you dont understand what that means there are answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean)

I suggest you wrap your code into [try...catch](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) blocks and retry, log, or end up script gracefully.

Comment: I don't understand what ChunkedEncodingError has to do with Connection broken.

Comment: according to urls requests documentation, it means `The server declared chunked encoding but sent an invalid chunk`

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/

Comment: OK thx.. but the server is not mine.. it's of a service provider that i'm connecting to. I assume that's a problem from his side? I'm not sure what useful info I can report other than sometimes this happens?

Comment: Before reporting, I will try to catch the exception and retry the failed request. Also I would slow down the rate at which am sending data to the server. Some servers don't like to be overwhelmed with many requests

Comment: how can I control over the request rate?

Comment: first control number of thread that connects to the server. And in each thread put sleep to some time (you can test the time that your servers are comfortable with) before sending new request

Comment: How can I put some to sleep and some now? all threads execute the same code.