# Spring boot netty issue

Tags: spring-boot, netty

Getting below issue when i fired request to spring boot (internally using Netty server)

2019-02-21 07:28:21.647 ERROR 9 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer              : [id: 0x460eebde, L:/10.0.125.18:80 - R:/10.0.125.55:56958] onUncaughtException(SimpleConnection{channel=[id: 0x460eebde, L:/10.0.125.18:80 - R:/10.0.125.55:56958]})

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

at io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor.readAddress(..)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.31.Final.jar!/:4.1.31.Final]`enter code here`

Comment: ["Connection reset by peer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) - for some reason the remote computer that you're trying to connect to (or a proxy server that's in between) rejects the connection.