# What might be causing these warning exceptions in my Artemis service logs?

Tags: netty, activemq-artemis

I'm seeing a lot of these warnings in my Artemis server logs and I'd like to understand what is triggering them?

```
[io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

The only things I've tried is to understand the origin of the issue.

This is from within Artemis server code.

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is the "Connection reset by peer" which is explained in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean). ActiveMQ Artemis is simply logging that the connection was reset. There's nothing it can actually do about it.

I recommend you investigate the clients accessing the broker as well as the network between them all to ensure they are operating properly.