# How to make Python requests persist in getting head

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a problem where Python requests is throwing an exception after a few seconds.  The website is being very slow, but only intermittently.

Chrome and Safari both fail to load the page.  (E.g. Chrome displays "This site can't be reached", ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).  However, Firefox is consistently able to access the page, although it takes around 20 secs to load.  This behaviour is repeatable from several different machines, located in different countries.  It seems like Firefox is "trying harder", and not timing out.

I'd like to get Python's requests to behave more like Firefox in this case. I have set the `timeout` argument to be a large number (60-seconds), but the exception is thrown long before that.  It seems like there is some kind of handshake timeout, whereas maybe the `timeout` parameter controls the wait time for the response, post-handshake?

```
import requests
target='https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gens/prod/gefs.20191113/00/pgrb2a/'
request = requests.head(target, timeout=60)
print(request.status_code)
```

^^ replace `20191113` with yesterday's date, as these links expire after 7-days.

The exception arrives after around 5-seconds, and is the "standard" requests exception when it can't access a page:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    257     def _read_status(self):
--> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
    299             else:
--> 300                 return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
    301 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
    289             else:
--> 290                 raise SocketError(str(e))
    291         except OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError as e:

OSError: (54, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    444                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 445                     timeout=timeout
    446                 )

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    366             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 367                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    368             elif read is not None:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    257     def _read_status(self):
--> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
    299             else:
--> 300                 return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
    301 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
    289             else:
--> 290                 raise SocketError(str(e))
    291         except OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError as e:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e4852eeb80e3> in <module>()
      2 import requests
      3 target='https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gens/prod/gefs.20191113/00/pgrb2a/'
----> 4 request = requests.head(target, timeout=60)
      5 print(request.status_code)

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in head(url, **kwargs)
     96 
     97     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', False)
---> 98     return request('head', url, **kwargs)
     99 
    100 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    510         }
    511         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 512         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    513 
    514         return resp

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    620 
    621         # Send the request
--> 622         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    623 
    624         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/miniconda/envs/basics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    493 
    494         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 495             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    496 
    497         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))
```

Is there a way to get Requests to "try harder" for slow pages?

This is Python3.6 and requests2.19.1

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stack trace the connection does not timeout but is rejected by to host ('ECONNRESET'). For more information about the error see the question "[What does “connection reset by peer” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean)"

Instead of increasing the timeout you need to retry the request. To avoid spamming the host there should be some time between the retries. You could write your own retry logic or use a library like [backoff](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/).

Below is an example from the backoff's documentation which will retry on any error for 60 seconds using exponential backoff strategy.

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_time=60)
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do retry the request, reset every time.  I don't understand why it would be reset for Requests/Chrome/Safari, but not Firefox.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to make a host/peer less eager to reset the connection?

Comment: @JK1 I a not too familiar with browser internals. Maybe Firefox is more patient in retrying. If the server cannot or won't handle the requests, there is little that can be done on the client-side. You could try retrying for a longer time and increase the time between retries.