# "Connection reset by peer" for Java HttpClient request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, java-11, java-http-client

I'm using **SpringBoot** with **JDK 11**.
This application is deployed on a container (AWS).

Into my REST Controllers I need to call internally external REST api services (using `TLS 1.2`)
I'm using `java.net.http.HttpClient` for this.

```
httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
```

(I'm using only one httpClient for all requests)

Sometimes (randomically) these requests fail.
Into my logs I see as cause of this problem:

> Connection reset by peer

This is strange for me. As already explained, this error does not happen systematically.

I analysed my code but I don't notice anything wrong.

Any suggestion?

Is the HttpClient initialization correct?

Is possible that the cause it's related to my code or from the external services?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean?

Comment: How frequent the issue is? If it's not frequent then adding a retry would make sense, else debug the network traffic, not sure if increasing connection timeout would help (but give it a try).

Comment: completely random.. sometimes 8% of the requests fails, sometimes 4% sometimes 0%

Comment: Do you know what version of the HTTP protocol your requests are being sent with? The `HttpClient` uses a connection pool for HTTP/1.1 requests - and it is possible that the server's policy for idle connections has a keepalive timeout that is less than the default `HttpClient` keepalive time. That might increase the chances of having the connection arbitrarily closed by the server side while the client is attempting to send a new request.
You could try playing with `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=<number-of-seconds>` ad see if it changes anything.

Comment: in this my case, I don't understand if it's better to have very long timeout values or not. What's the default value for httpClient (if I understand correctly, the default it's 20m).