# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer in Django

Tags: django, connection-reset

I am running my django site still on my development folder. I have started getting this error. Which I am not sure what the cause is. The site does load with all the images and styling but I can't get rid of this. I am not sure if this is causing more issues in my site.

This is the error in the terminal

[image: Terminal Error]

Settings.py file Debug set to True

[image: Setting.py file]

Comment: Does it happen whenever you want to access any url on your application or when you access a specific url?

Comment: Check out this answer, might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434592/7065267

Comment: Yes it happens when I refresh any page, it may be an issue in the base.html template calling some file. I am not sure.