PHP fgetcsv on a huge csv file, error SSL: Connection reset by peer
Php fgetcsv script to update a database by loading a csv file of 115000 rows but after about 111000 rows it stops with this error

Warning: fgetcsv(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in "script folder".

I tried to increase all the values ​​of the php.ini but I always get this error, I can't figure out what stops it.
It always stops after 4.8632356325785 seconds
What causes this block?
I changed all the execution and memory limit values
The error refers to this line
while (($data_string = fgetcsv($handle, ";")) !== FALSE) {

$row = 1;

$url = $_POST['url_file'];
$handle = fopen($url,"r");

$done = 0;

while (($data_string = fgetcsv($handle, ";")) !== FALSE) {

    $num = count($data_string);
    $row++;
    $ean13 = "";
    $price = "";
    $quantity = "";
    $data = explode(";",$data_string[0]);
    echo ob_get_clean();


Did you try to just download the CSV from your php script?

I suggest you split the csv file and load multiples, this may make it easier to track down the line that is causing issue or if it is a memory issue will allow you to load multiples and make it work.

As I already said in the staging ground, you should download the file first, then call fgetcsv() on it.

"Connection reset by peer" probably means that it is the computer where the file is coming from is terminating the connection. Why? No idea. You haven't told us anything about it, nor, for instance, how large the CSV file is. But I agree with the other commenters, first do a normal file upload to your server and only then process it.

For ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean

I think you have summarised your code too much. You have removed a lot of the relevant code.

Also the code will not run!!! The fgetcsv($handle, ";") call will generate an error. Please, don't show us a simulation of your code, see how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example those we can work with

@KIKO-Software the csv file is about 30 mb, it is first uploaded to the server then the script starts. The script itself works, but it gets to 80% of the file and then stops with that error.
If I divide the file into multiple parts everything works correctly, there is something in the process that blocks but I can't figure out what is blocking it

Your code speaks of an $url, not a file path. This implies the http protocol. If you first upload the file to your server you should be using the normal file system, and not the http protocol. Also note that RiggsFolly correctly remarked that your code cannot run. I think all this shows us you've asked a question with code you're not actually using and didn't test.

Yes I know I put part of the code, only in the second part there are references to the tables of my Db that I am going to update, I did not want to make them public. The data is read and possibly updated.
